# How to create a batch file to retrieve a password from a password generator?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, passwords

I want to create a batch file to retrieve a password from an EXE on the computer. It is a password that changes everyday.

I don't get any results with the code below.

```
set /p input="C:\Program Files\Password\PasswordGenerator
if %input%==q3Ym9fb goto YES

if not %input%==q3Ym9fb goto NO

:YES

echo correct password
pause

:NO

echo incorrect password 
pause
```

Comment: `set /p input` is for getting keyboard input, not the output from running a command.

Comment: You need to use [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to parse the output from `C:\Program Files\Password\PasswordGenerator`

Comment: @DavidPostill: There are other problems with his script, if you are minded to give an answer.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not, primarily because I'm not sure what he is actually trying to achieve. Feel free to answer if you want.

Comment: I am trying to get the password from a password generator tool and save it where I can use the password to schedule a task. Also the password generator will only generate letters and number no special characters.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set a variable to the result of a command is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`command`) DO SET var=%%F
ECHO %var%
```

In case of any error your IF command might have a syntax error, and also if
the password generator returns a string with non-alphanumeric characters.

You should be comparing strings like this:

```
if "%input%"=="q3Ym9fb" goto YES
```

I also note that by reversing the order of the YES and NO labels,
your second IF becomes redundant.

In addition, after returning from the PAUSE of the first label, execution will
continue to the second label. If that is not your intention, you should add
an [EXIT command](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html).

Comment: Where `"tokens=*"` will strip leading spaces from command output (what ***may*** be desired). To get unmodified output use `"delims="`